# Get values of array of Firestore Database extra

Tags: javascript, database, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting values of Firestore and add them to an array list with the following JavaScript code:

```
var mdlPoints = [];
var schrPoints = [];

db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            const data = doc.data();
            mdlPoints.push(data.mdl);
            schrPoints.push(data.klu);

            console.log("mdl: " + data.mdl);
            console.log("klu: " + data.klu);
        });
```

The structure looks like this:
[image: db structure]

As you can see all the fields are stored with an ArrayList ( `klu`: [4,9] or `mdl`: [5]). As you can see in my JavaScript code I want to add the single numbers to my array list in js.

This works perfectly for array lists who have only one content, like in the picture the `mdl` with content number 5. But on array lists with more content numbers like in the picture the `klu` with the numbers 4 and 9.

So when I print the output values I get something like this: `klu: 4,9`. And this value is added to array list with this line: `schrPoints.push(data.klu);` **But** I in a case such that I can **NOT** add `4,9` to the list. I must add `4` and `9` separate without a comma.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(data.klu[0]);` and `console.log(data.klu[1]);`?

Comment: @ Hensler Software Yes with that I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the answer of @Hensler Software I fixed my problem this way:

```
db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        const data = doc.data();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.mdl.length; i++) {
          mdlPoints.push(data.mdl[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < data.klu.length; i++) {
          schrPoints.push(data.klu[i]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: No problem. Good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single value, you could use the array method `split()` for `["4,9"]` to separate `4` and `9`.

Like this:

```js
var newKluArray = data.klu.split(',') // [4, 9] array with 2 values
```

If it is done or already is more than one value in the array, then you can select numbers separetely, like this:

```js
newKluArray[0]; // 4
newKluArray[1]; // 9
```

So you can manipulate or add them as you wish.

Comment: The content returned from firestore is not a string it's an array.

Comment: I see, but why exactly you cannot manipulate each value just selecting by index?